ERROR WITH SELECTOR USING WEBDRIVER IN PYTHON
there is a page that is similar to a calculator, my intention is that given a number that I have established, create a code that clicks on each of those numbers on the page
try:
# Number to find
number_to_find= "71722336"

#loop
for number in number_to_find:
    selector = f"li.digits strong:contains('{number}')"
    boton_number= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)
    boton_number.click()
    print("Number", number, "clicked!.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
except Exception as e:
print("Error to find and clicking the number:", e)

but the code throws the following error:
the structure of the bottons is this
Message: javascript error: {"status":32,"value":"An invalid or illegal selector was specified"}
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.106)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF788C270C2+63090]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788B92D12]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A2EC65]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A33D21]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A36159]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A36200]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A7460C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A74ADC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788AB5B37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A9701F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788AB3412]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A96D83]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A683A8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788A69441]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF78902262D+4238301]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF78905F78D+4488509]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF789057A6F+4456479]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF788D00606+953270]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788B9E5DF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788B992B4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788B993EB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF788B89C24]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFED6EF7344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFED84026B1+33]

the structure of the bottons is this

Does anyone know what causes this error or what is wrong in the code?

It seems like your css selector is not able to find the element. For newer versions, for invalid selector it raises a javascript error as shown. Why don't you try xpath? //li[@class="digits"]/strong[contains(text(),'${number}')]

If you can share the website I may run it and tell you more about the error.

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

Indent is crucial in python... please fix your code indent.

There is no CSS selector that allows searching for an element by contained text. There was one temporarily several years ago but it was cut. The only way to do this now is using an XPath.
Some suggestions...

Avoid controlling flow using exceptions. Use .find_elements() and test that the returned collection is empty instead.
Don't wrap large blocks of code in try-except. It just makes it harder to debug. Let it throw an exception... once you learn how to read call stacks, it's invaluable in debugging issues quickly.
Only use try-except for specific exceptions and only when you are going to handle them, e.g. don't catch Exception... it's way too broad.

The code below should work
number_to_find = "71722336"
for number in number_to_find:
    digits = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//li[@class='digits']//strong[text()='{number}']")
    if digits:
        digits[0].click()
    else:
        print(f"Element containing <{number}> not found.")
    time.sleep(0.5)

